# CallWndProc Example

Tags: c#, .net, hook

This is my first time experimenting with `hooks`.

I'm looking for some good resources for implementing a `CallWndProc hook`. The MSDN stuff is a bit overwhelming.

I have discovered that with this type of hook a external dll needs to be injected. That's mainly where I'm stuck.

Not sure what needs to be in the dll and what needs to be in the `.NET` app.

Any dll examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook in a managed language like C#. So you need more than just an external DLL, you need an external DLL written in a language that compiles down to native code, like C or C++.

[The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx) is actually pretty good, especially the [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx). There's even an example on the [Using Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960.aspx) page.

I don't mean to sound discouraging, but if you find that overwhelming, you're going to have a fair bit of trouble getting this to work right. Hooks are a very advanced technique in Windows programming. You need to understand window procedures, message loops, and the other basics of Windows applications before you undertake a project like this one. It also obviously helps to know either the C or C++ languages well, since that's what you'll be using!

Anyway, I just happen to have a hook DLL that I've written in C handy, so I'll try to pull out some of the relevant code. It actually installs a `WH_CALLWNDRETPROC` hook, but the two are quite similar. The hook procedure for this one is called *after* the window procedure has processed the message; the one you're talking about is called *before* the window procedure has processed the message.

```
/* The handle to the hook is stored as a shared global variable and is the
 * same for all hooked processes. We achieve that by placing it in the
 * shared data segment of the DLL.
 *
 * Note that shared global variables must be explicitly initialized.
 *
 * And also note that this is really not the ideal way of doing this; it's just
 * an easy way to get going. The better solution is to use a memory-mapped file.
 * See Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0.aspx
 */
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.SHARED,rws")
#pragma data_seg(".SHARED") /* begin the shared data segment */
   HHOOK g_hhkCallWndProcRet = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()          /* end the shared data segment and default back to normal behavior */


LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndRetProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   /* If nCode is greater than or equal to HC_ACTION,
    * we should process the message. */
   if (nCode >= HC_ACTION)
   {
      /* Retrieve a pointer to the structure that contains details about
       * the message, and see if it is one that we want to handle. */
      const LPCWPRETSTRUCT lpcwprs = (LPCWPRETSTRUCT)lParam;
      switch (lpcwprs->message)
      {
         /* ...SNIP: process the messages we're interested in ... */
      }
   }

   /* At this point, we are either not processing the message
    * (because nCode is less than HC_ACTION),
    * or we've already finished processing it.
    * Either way, pass the message on. */
   return CallNextHookEx(g_hhkCallWndProcRet, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


BOOL __stdcall InstallHook(void)
{
   /* Try to install the WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hook,
    * if it is not already installed. */
   if (!g_hhkCallWndProcRet)
   {
      g_hhkCallWndProcRet = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET,
                                             CallWndRetProc,
                                             g_hinstDLL,
                                             0);
      if (!g_hhkCallWndProcRet)
      {
         /* ...SNIP: handle failure condition ... */
         return FALSE;
      }
   }

   return TRUE;  /* return success */
}

BOOL __stdcall RemoveHook(void)
{
   /* Try to remove the WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hook, if it is installed. */
   if (g_hhkCallWndProcRet)
   {
      if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hhkCallWndProcRet))
      {
         /* ...SNIP: handle failure condition ... */
         return FALSE;
      }
      g_hhkCallWndProcRet = NULL;
   }

   return TRUE;  /* return success */
}
```

Comment: So to use this in a C# application do you just DLLImport InstallHook() and RemoveHook() or am I completely off track?

Comment: *sigh* Don't be helpless. `g_hinstDll` is a global variable that contains a handle to the DLL instance. You get the DLL instance in your `DllMain` entry point, called when the DLL is first loaded. You should save it and store it in a global variable. Call it whatever you want and declare it wherever you want. I called it `g_hinstDll`. @RegEdit

Answer (score 0):

i write a code about Windows Hook kind of  WH_CALLWNDPROC . i 'd like share with you .

```
LRESULT Widget::HookMessageProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    
    if (nCode >= HC_ACTION)
    {
        tagCWPSTRUCT* tagCwp = (tagCWPSTRUCT*)lParam;
        QString str = QString("handle =%1,message=%2,lp=%3,lw=%4").arg(QString::number((int)tagCwp->hwnd)).arg(QString::number(tagCwp->message)).arg(QString::number(tagCwp->lParam)).arg(QString::number(tagCwp->wParam));

        QFile file("d:\\text.txt");
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text|QIODevice::Append);
        file.write(str.toUtf8()+"\n");
        file.close();
        return 0;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_wndHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
HMODULE hApp1 = GetModuleHandle(0); //Get Self Handler .
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, HookProc, hApp1 , GetCurrentThreadId());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    **after i run it , it shows \n:
    handle =2426644,message=36,lp=368934118416,lw=0
    handle =2426644,message=129,lp=368934118336,lw=0
    handle =2426644,message=70,lp=368934114496,lw=0
    handle =2426644,message=131,lp=368934114448,lw=1 
    handle =2426644,message=71,lp=368934114496,lw=0
    handle =2426644,message=3,lp=29950894,lw=0
    handle =2426644,message=5,lp=32506532,lw=0
    handle =2426644,message=127,lp=0,lw=2
    handle =2426644,message=127,lp=0,lw=0
    handle =2426644,message=127,lp=0,lw=1
    handle =199294,message=129,lp=368934118336,lw=0
    handle =199294,message=131,lp=368934118448,lw=0
    handle =199294,message=1,lp=368934118336,lw=0
    handle =199294,message=5,lp=0,lw=0
    So i am very confused now ,what does these data mean , how to PARSE the 
    parameters of lParam,and wParam .**
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).