# Edit parent in inheritance chain while maintaining base parents \ children

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following .Net inheritance chains:

- Control -> ButtonBase -> Button
- Control -> Label
- Control -> ScrollableControl -> Panel

I want to edit the Control Class, but want to use the .Net children of this parent.

I am imagining this to look something like this?

```
    public class TouchControl : Control
    {
        public event MouseEventHandler TouchDown, TouchUp;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
        {
            if(m == a)
            {TouchDown(Object, MouseEventArgs);}
            else if (m == b)
            {TouchUp(Object, MouseEventArgs);}
        }
    }   

    public class TouchButtonBase : TouchControl
    {
        // Inherits from TouchControl but implements ButtonBase Class
    }

    public class TouchButton : TouchButtonBase
    {
        // Inherits TouchButtonBase but implements Button Class 
    }

    public class TouchLabel: TouchControl
    {
        // Inherits TouchControl but implements Label Class
    }
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

My current approach violates the DRY principle and I would like to fix this:

```
    public class TouchPanel : Panel
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
        {
            //Repeated functionality
        }
    }

    public class TouchButton  : Button
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            //Repeated functionality
        }
    }

    public class TouchPictureBox : PictureBox
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            //Repeated functionality
        }
    }

    public class TouchLabel: Label
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            //Repeated functionality
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"implements [x] class"*? You can only inherit from one class, but you can implement many interfaces. I'm confused because you haven't shown any interfaces in the question.

Comment: @RufusL I want it to be the standard .Net class that it would usually be, just with one function overridden in its parent's class.

Comment: Ah, I see. Not sure you can do that, but you could create an extension method for the `Control` class (with a different name than `WndProc`), and either use that method instead or redirect calls to `WndProc` to that method (basically putting the "repeated functionality" in one place).

Comment: I don't think you can intercept the inheritance chain this way. You might be able to meet your goals using a [WndProc hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644975(v=vs.85)), but in c# that is [rather involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747619/2791540)

Comment: The window subclassing design in Win32 was very flexible and would have allowed composing several subclasses like this, but .NET has none of that flexibility.