# How can I trigger a WinForms app when I open another Desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, process

I want to trigger a WinForms app when I open notepad.exe. How can I do that?

So far I've tried the Process Class. Here when you run the C# Program, then the external application is executed. MDI keeps the external application in the form.

I want to create an overlay for notepad.exe. The overlay being the child window and notepad.exe being the parent window.

However, I want execution of notepad.exe to trigger the WinForms app.

Comment: It's a bit complicated, but could be done.  You need to register a global hook to WH_CALLWNDPROC, and compile that as a DLL.  Then you can have code in that DLL that monitors when a Notepad's window class is being invoked and can trigger your WinForms app.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747619

Comment: What does *trigger a WinForms app* mean? Is the application already running? If it's not, you can use a window-less process that subscribes to WMI Process notification events (requires admin access) or UIAutomation's `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent`. Then your Process is notified whenever a new Process is run or a Window is created, anywhere in the System and it can start the application, if it's not running, or bring it to front or whatever.

Comment: You also have [Shell Event Notifications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130614-00/?p=4083) ([DShellWindowsEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/dshellwindowsevents), similar to UIAutomation's events)

Comment: See also [RegisterShellHookWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registershellhookwindow)