# SetWindowsHookEx Get Window Messages from Java FFI gives Access Denied

Tags: java, windows, ffi

While trying to hook into a GUI window I get Access Denied.

I have tried calling
`SetWindowsHookExA(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, pointerToHookProcUpcall, nullptr, WindowThreadProcessId)`
and `SetWindowsHookExA(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, pointerToHookProcUpcall, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), WindowThreadProcessId)`
without success.

I have tried running the Java process as admin and turning off UAC, but to no avail.

What I am trying to do is overlay the application using java though the Foreign Function Interface. The process is selected based on Exe names and window titles, with the target program running without administrator(for example: Notepad++)[image: Process Selection and Error]

Comment: can you please read that remarks section. it is going to help you to solve your problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#remarks

Comment: @GurhanPolat the bitness matches, and I have tried both anyways

Comment: can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747619/2016727